# How to calculate time elapsed between rows in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have date and time as separate columns, which i combined into a single column using library(lubridate)
Now i want to create a new column that would calculate the elapsed time between two consecutive rows for each unique ID

I tried diff, however the error i am getting is that the new column has +1 rows compared to original data set

```
s1$DT<-with(s1, mdy(Date.of.Collection) + hm(MILITARY.TIME))#this worked - #needs the library lubridate
s1$ElapsedTime<-difff(s1$DT)
units(s1$ElapsedTime)<-"hours"
```

```
Subject.ID  time    DT  Time elapsed
1   Dose    8/1/2018 8:15   0
1   time point1 8/1/2018 9:56   0.070138889
1   time point2 8/2/2018 9:56   1.070138889
2   Dose    9/4/2018 10:50  0
2   time point1 9/11/2018 11:00 7.006944444
3   Dose    10/1/2018 10:20 0
3   time point1 10/2/2018 14:22 1.168055556
3   time point2 10/3/2018 12:15 2.079861111
```

Comment: you should use difftime(x, shift(x), units='hours')

Comment: (1) your code is not right (typo, `difff`), please make sure you are pasting in what you are using, not just typing it in manually. (2) How about `s1$ElapsedTime <- c(0, diff(s1$DT))`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico could you please explain your code, when i tried this - its asking for time 2, i would like the code to calculate the time difference between two cells, For example T1-T0, T2-T0,T3-T0...........................Tn-T0

Comment: @r2evans - i received a column - sure however i think its calculating the time diff between two consecutive cells. I would like one of the cells to be constant  as explained below: T1-T0, T2-T0,T3-T0...........................Tn-T0, also the loop would need to restart once R sees a new identifier [which is ID in this case]

Comment: @r2evans to throw a wrench into this - what if there was an additional time point called screenning and i would still like to know the difference between this "screening time " and my dose ( it would be in negative )   would liek somewhat like this :Subject.ID time1 DT Time elapsed
1 Screening 7/31/2018 8:15 -1
1 Dose 8/1/2018 8:15 0
1 time_point1 8/1/2018 9:56 0.070138889
1 time_point2 8/2/2018 9:56 1.070138889
2 screening 9/3/2018 10:50 -1
2 Dose 9/4/2018 10:50 0
2 time_point1 9/11/2018 11:00 7.006944444
3 Screening  9/30/2018 10:50 -1
3 Dose 10/1/2018 10:20 0

Comment: Data (and complex code) in comments is typically bad. I suggest you open a new question and include a reference to this question and the added constraints/expected-output.

Comment: @r2evans will do - also i figured it out , do.call(
  rbind,
  by(patients, patients$Subject.ID, function(x) {
    x$elapsed <- x$realDT - x$realDT[2]
    units(x$elapsed) <- "hours"
    x
  })
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, you don't need a "diff"; in conventional R-speak, a "diff" would be *T<sub>1</sub>-T<sub>0</sub>*, *T<sub>2</sub>-T<sub>1</sub>*, *T<sub>3</sub>-T<sub>2</sub>*, ..., *T<sub>n</sub> - T<sub>n-1</sub>*.

For you, one of these will work to give you *T<sub>1,2,...,n</sub> - T<sub>0</sub>*.

### Base R

```r
do.call(
  rbind,
  by(patients, patients$Subject.ID, function(x) {
    x$elapsed <- x$realDT - x$realDT[1]
    units(x$elapsed) <- "hours"
    x
  })
)
#     Subject.ID       time1        DT  Time          elapsed              realDT
# 1.1          1        Dose  8/1/2018  8:15   0.000000 hours 2018-08-01 08:15:00
# 1.2          1 time_point1  8/1/2018  9:56   1.683333 hours 2018-08-01 09:56:00
# 1.3          1 time_point2  8/2/2018  9:56  25.683333 hours 2018-08-02 09:56:00
# 2.4          2        Dose  9/4/2018 10:50   0.000000 hours 2018-09-04 10:50:00
# 2.5          2 time_point1 9/11/2018 11:00 168.166667 hours 2018-09-11 11:00:00
# 3.6          3        Dose 10/1/2018 10:20   0.000000 hours 2018-10-01 10:20:00
# 3.7          3 time_point1 10/2/2018 14:22  28.033333 hours 2018-10-02 14:22:00
# 3.8          3 time_point2 10/3/2018 12:15  49.916667 hours 2018-10-03 12:15:00
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
patients %>%
  group_by(Subject.ID) %>%
  mutate(elapsed = `units<-`(realDT - realDT[1], "hours")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
patDT <- copy(patients)
setDT(patDT)
patDT[, elapsed := `units<-`(realDT - realDT[1], "hours"), by = "Subject.ID"]
```

---

Notes:

- The "hours" in the `$elapsed` column is just an artifact of dealing with a time-difference thing, it should not affect most operations. To get rid of it, make sure you're in the right units ("hours", "secs", ..., see [`?units`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/difftime)) and use `as.numeric`.
- The only reasons I used `as.POSIXct` as above are that I'm not a `lubridate` user, and the data as provided is not in a time format. You shouldn't need it if your `Time` is a proper time format, in which case you'd use that field instead of my hacky `realDT`.
- On similar lines, if you do calculate `realDT` and use it, you really don't need both `realDT` and the pair of `DT` and `Time`.

The data I used:

```r
patients <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Subject.ID  time1    DT  Time elapsed
1   Dose    8/1/2018 8:15   0
1   time_point1 8/1/2018 9:56   0.070138889
1   time_point2 8/2/2018 9:56   1.070138889
2   Dose    9/4/2018 10:50  0
2   time_point1 9/11/2018 11:00 7.006944444
3   Dose    10/1/2018 10:20 0
3   time_point1 10/2/2018 14:22 1.168055556
3   time_point2 10/3/2018 12:15 2.079861111")
# this is necessary for me because DT/Time here are not POSIXt (they're just strings)
patients$realDT <- as.POSIXct(paste(patients$DT, patients$Time), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: all the methods worked - so Thank you !,once additional question for the data table methods the output is in seconds, how do i change that to say hours , i tried using setDT(PK4)[, elapsed := realDT - realDT[1], by = "Subject.ID",units='hour']- i changed the object name to not confuse myself later on with a command line which is setDT and actual unique data table i have which is PK4 for example

Comment: Oops, meant to do the same for all. Just use the `\`units<-\`(...)` code I had in "dplyr" (now edited).

Comment: BTW: I provided all three because it is not always obvious of the asker's intentions. They all do the same thing, do the one to use depends on (1) your preference, and (2) whatever fits with the rest of your project. If you're already using tidyverse-based packages, perhaps stick with the `dplyr` implementation; if your tables are obscenely large and you are concerned about memory/speed, you can lean towards the `data.table` version; if you are concerned about package-requirement bloat, go with base R. \*shrug\*

Comment: Agree compeletely - i tried all three so as to whoever sees this thread knows all three methods work so - yeap- thanks again